# Odata c# dynamic query between dates

Tags: c#, linq, odata

I need to create a dynamic query for odata,
http://xxx/odata/products?$filter=createDate+gt+2018-03-01T00:00:00%2B02:00+and+createDate+lt+2018-03-31T23:59:59%2B03:00

The query should filter all the products with the createDate on the current Month.
Something like:

$filter=createDate+gt+MonthFirstDay(today)+and+createDate+lt+MonthLastDay(today).

Thank you very much

Comment: So what's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: I need the query to be dynamic, that means I need it to query the use the current month and not an hard coded one.

Comment: This might help you get started: [Create an OData v4 Client App (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app)

Comment: So use string interpolation or something similar. Did you try anything at all? How are you making this OData call?

Comment: I do not have access to the query filter after it saved, I use the query in a report mechanism, I need the query to be dynamic and independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.OData.Query;

namespace Business.BusinessLogic.Translators
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert odata query using keywords
    /// </summary>
    public class ODataQueryConverter : IODataQueryConverter
    {
        private readonly DateTime _serverNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        private Dictionary<string, string> KeywordsDictionary { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// constructor
        /// </summary>
        public ODataQueryConverter()
        {
            KeywordsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "StartOfTheMonth", new DateTime(_serverNow.Year, _serverNow.Month, 1).ToString(Consts.IsoPattern)},
                { "EndOfTheMonth", new DateTime(_serverNow.Year, _serverNow.Month +1,1).AddSeconds(-1).ToString(Consts.IsoPattern)},
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert OData query option to new uri using const keywords
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="odataQuery"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ODataQueryOptions Convert(ODataQueryOptions odataQuery)
        {
            if (odataQuery == null)
                return null;

            var odataRequestMessage = odataQuery.Request;
            var odataRequestUri = odataRequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();
            var newRequestUriString = ConvertKeywords(odataRequestUri);

            odataRequestMessage.RequestUri = new Uri(newRequestUriString);
            var newOdataQueryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(odataQuery.Context, odataRequestMessage);

            return newOdataQueryOptions;
        }

        public string Convert(string odataQueryString)
        {
            return ConvertKeywords(odataQueryString);
        }

        private string ConvertKeywords(string odataRequestUri)
        {
            return KeywordsDictionary.Aggregate(odataRequestUri, (current, keyword) => current.Replace(keyword.Key, keyword.Value));
        }
    }
}

//method in my BaseODataController used to query data 
//_converter is the instance of ODataQueryConverter that I got from depedency injection
public virtual IQueryable<T> Get(ODataQueryOptions<T> queryOptions)
{
   var convertedQuery = _converter.Convert(queryOptions);
   var queryable = BusinessController.Get();
   var convertedQueryable = convertedQuery.ApplyTo(queryable);
   return convertedQueryable;
}
```

Now every request from `odata` would go through the converter and look for the keywords we set in the converter dictionary.
If the converter finds any it will replace it with the corresponding values.

Now I can use:
http://api.dev.com/odata/entity?$filter=dateTime+gt+StartOfTheMonth

And it would automatically translated to:
http://api.dev.com/odata/entity?$filter=dateTime+gt+2018-03-001T00:00:00.000Z

We created one source of truth for the keywords instead of letting each endpoint
translate the keywords itself.

If anyone knows a way to do it with the current Odata version, please post it here.